# Powershell - Comparing two files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two csv files, one column each, one with numbers(4590987), one with numbers with extensions (4590987.htm). I would like to find all the matches, and write those to another csv file so I can then use that to get the files out of folder and copy them to 
another folder for further processing. I have the csv files sorted, with headers, but cannot figure out how to compare and write out the result. Or comparing the list of numbers to the contents of the folder and copying those files out. The only problem there is my list is about 3000 lines and the directory has about 45000 files in it, so I am worried it could take a while.

```
 $csv1 = Import-Csv $readfilebasesorted1
 $csv2 = Import-Csv $readlistsorted1

   $hash = @{} 

    $match = "^\d{7}"

     $funmatch = ([regex]::matches($csv1, $match))

        foreach ($line in $funmatch){

           foreach ($lines in $csv2){
            if ($line -match $lines){

               $hash += $line
               $hash = Write-Output $result
               }
            }
   }
```

---

New Code, hopefully formatted a little better.

```
    $a = Import-CSV "C:\read\20140630.csv" - header("ProID","EventDate","EventType","EventNotes")
    $scrdir = '\\pl1\Prolaw\gwdocs\4754-66921'
    $sortedlist = 'C:\ProLaw\sortedlist.csv'
    $docs = 'C:\ProLaw\Docs'

    # Sort 
    $sort = $a | Sort-Object ProID | Export-Csv $sortedlist -NoTypeInformation


    $listtomove = Import-Csv $sortedlist
    $scrdir = '\\pl1\Prolaw\gwdocs\4754-66921' 

    GCI $scrdir | ?{$listtomove.ProID -contains $_.BaseName} | Select -Expand FullName |  Copy-Item -Destination $docs
```

Comment: What are your headers? You don't show them in your code. With those I'll have an answer for you.

Comment: Look at the `Compare-Object` cmdlet also.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, no, this is why you have the -in and -contains operators!

Ok, so here's what you do. Pull a directory listing, and for each file, if it's name is listed in your CSV list of numbers, move that file to wherever. Assuming you have a column with the header FileName that has all the numbers listed in it here's what it would look something like:

```
$ListToMove = Import-CSV $readlistsorted1
$Source = <Path to files>
$Destination = <Path to folder where they need to go>

GCI $Source | ?{$ListToMove.FileName -contains $_.BaseName} |Select -Expand FullName| Move-Item -Destination $Destination
```

**Edit:** Ok, here's your code, combined with mine, so that it should work for what you want:

```
$a = Import-CSV "C:\read\20140630.csv" -header("ProID","EventDate","EventType","EventNotes") 
$scrdir = '\\pl1\Prolaw\gwdocs\4754-66921' 
$docs = 'C:\ProLaw\Docs'
GCI $scrdir | ?{$a.ProID -contains $_.BaseName} | Select -Expand FullName | Copy-Item -Destination $docs
```

Comment: Okay, so I have reworked this according to your code other than using Copy-Item instead of Move-Item as I need the files to stay in the current directory also. The code runs without errors, but nothing is copied to my folder.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question that I posed in my first comment. What are your CSV headers?

Comment: $a = Import-CSV "C:\read\20140630.csv" -header("ProID","EventDate","EventType","EventNotes")
$scrdir = '\\pl1\Prolaw\gwdocs\4754-66921'
$sortedlist = 'C:\ProLaw\sortedlist.csv'
$docs = 'C:\ProLaw\Docs'

 # Sort 
     $sort = $a | Sort-Object ProID | Export-Csv $sortedlist -NoTypeInformation
   

    $listtomove = Import-Csv $sortedlist
    $scrdir = '\\pl1\Prolaw\gwdocs\4754-66921' 
    
    GCI $scrdir | ?{$listtomove.ProID -contains $_.BaseName} | Select -Expand FullName | Copy-Item -Destination $docs

Comment: Headers are shown in code above. I am using the ProID header as the $_.BaseName

Comment: Answer updated, with your code modified, let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Tested code, it runs and does not error, but does not copy any files.

Comment: Hm, I tested it on my end with mocked up CSV and files in a folder and it worked fine. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.